# Why am I getting TS2322 only under certain circumstances?

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I am trying to generate HTML documentation on my TypeScript project using [Typedoc](https://typedoc.org).

In one of the many files, there is this bit of code:

```js
public doSomething(val: number | undefined | null | string): string | undefined | null {
  if (val === null || val === undefined || typeof val === 'string') {
    return val;
  }
  ...
```

WebStorm shows no errors; in fact, hovering over `val` in the `return` statement shows me that `val` is assumed to be of type `string | null | undefined`.

Compilation (i.e. running the application with `nx serve`) works flawlessly, as well. And the class this bit of code is contained in is instantiated in the main view of the web application.

Yet, when I try to build Typedoc, it fails on that `return` statement, saying:

> TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Apparently, whatever Typedoc uses to analyze that source code does not have the same capabilities of resolving type assertions as what is used when building the runnable application - but why? Where could I check and what could I reconfigure to make this work?

*Of course, I could change this one instance in the source code, but if we cannot trust Typedoc to work with the same source code as what our regular development environment uses, this gets really hard to handle with a time of > 100 people that constantly commit code and most of which do not specifically check Typedoc compatibility.*

---

EDIT: The target of the module where this code is located was set to `es2020`, but switching to `es2022` made no difference, neither to Typedoc nor to the build executed as a part of `nx serve`.

Even more strangely, if I copy and paste the *same* function elsewhere in the codebase, even Typedoc has no problems with compiling it there. There is a local `typedoc.config.json` file, but it only points to the general file and indicates the local entry points.

Comment: What is `valvalue`

Comment: @derpirscher: Sorry, that was a typo in the minimized sample. Fixed.

Comment: Are you really comparing `val` to the literal string constant`"string"` or do you want a typecheck, if `typeof val === "string"` If the first, what does this method return if `val` is for instance `"foobar"`?

Comment: @derpirscher: No, it's actually a `typeof` statement. Maybe I shouldn't be posting these questions in the evening ;)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, none of the other `return` statements in this method can lead to a number to be returned? Because that's what the error is actually saying. Ie, if your method returns something different from from `undefined` and `null` it has to be a `string`, but somewhere a return type of `string | number` is deducted, which isn't allowed

Comment: @derpirscher: The Typedoc output points out a specific line and column number - the one where the depicted `return` statement is located. I really don't think there is anything *generally* wrong with that code, as there *are* circumstances where the code compiles (this very same file gets compiled successfully when I run `nx serve`). There must be something about Typedoc's settings that cause the compilation during Typedoc generation to work differently than during `nx serve`, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

TypeDoc maintainer here.

`nx serve` does not perform type checking at all. You can verify this by adding a trivial type error with `parseInt(1)` and compiling.

Webstorm uses the compiler API *sometimes*. The team behind it decided that they could do a better job than TS in terms of type inference, which while sometimes helpful, means that in complex projects it frequently does not match what `tsc` will do, so it also cannot be relied on.

TypeDoc relies on the TypeScript compiler API to perform type checking. It does not do any itself. This means that any TypeScript errors coming out of TypeDoc should be completely reproducible with `npx tsc --noEmit --project path/to/tsconfig.typedoc.json`. If this is not the case, and you're able to provide a reproduction, please open an issue as it is a bug in TypeDoc.

It's impossible to say for sure what's going wrong here without a reproduction, but I suspect that you have other compiler errors which resulted in a cascading effect that caused this one. Unreachable code can produce errors like this.

```
declare function bar(x: number): void;

function foo(x: string | number) {
    if (true) {
        return x;
    }
    // Unreachable code detected.(7027)
    // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    //  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
    bar(x);
}
```

Comment: This is much better than my workaround + faulty explanation of why I think the workaround is necessary. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: read the better answer by @Gerrit0 and you probably don't need this, this answer was written before that)

If nothing else helps and you need a workaround: TypeDoc offers the option to skip type checking:
https://typedoc.org/options/other/#skiperrorchecking

```bash
typedoc --skipErrorChecking
```

But they warn this might lead to crashes.
Prefer the other answer.

Comment: This answer implies that type _conversion_ to models to be displayed in the docs is linked with type _checking_. It isn't, and TypeDoc does not perform any type checking itself. It instead calls the compiler API, so any compiler errors are coming from the official TS compiler.

Comment: @Gerrit0 I did not intend to say that, hopefully my edit clarifies this bit.

Comment: Still sounds like you're saying that TypeDoc might report compiler errors that don't come from the compiler to me. The linked issue shows that TypeDoc's displayed type might resolve aliases that the user wanted to be left alone, but those types are still equivalent from the compiler's perspective